# Add labels to Snapshots when creating them

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm using following code to create my snapshots with expected labels on them:

```
static async void TakeSnapshots(string zone, string diskName)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dict.Add("env", "prod");
    dict.Add("backup", "auto");

    Random r = new Random();

    Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.Snapshot snapshot = new Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.Snapshot()
    {
        Name = "test-" + r.Next(1, 1000),
        Description = "Description",
        Labels = dict
    };

    var request = computeService.Disks.CreateSnapshot(snapshot, project, zone, diskName);

    try
    {
        var response = await request.ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

But snapshots are being created without labels in them. Am I doing something wrong or things are broken?

Google.Apis.Compute.v1 SDK version is: 1.29.1.958

Comment: Hmm. That *looks* like I'd expect it to look. Are you able to set the labels correctly after the fact? Are the name and description correctly applied?

Comment: To help determine wheter the problem is in the API client library or in Google's servers, try getting a [network trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/network-tracing). A trace including the body of the request will show wheter the client actually sent the labels it was given.

Comment: Hi Jon, Yes. Currently i have only tested setting them from web pages manually. Name description gets set without any issues. Labels are only one missing.

Hi David, That would only work with full framework and I'm using .Net Core.

Comment: David, I managed to get network trace from that call. What should i look for from this log since it doesn't have full post request as clear text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In google-cloud, the creation of snapshot accepts only the attributes that are mandatory from the request-body dictionary.

Label is something which is to be added to a resource, which isn't a mandatory for the resource to get created. Hence, google-cloud code ignores the tags, labels sort of attributes from request.

You need to POST another request to add label resources.
Good thing that google-cloud handles is that: if you create a snapshot, even if the snapshot is not yet completed, you would be able to label resources through of-course another request.

Hence it doesn't actually blocks us to perform operations.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That makes sense why its not working.